# Updating an object with useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Hello I am trying to pass state up from a form to my `useState` hook in the parent component but nothing happens when I submit my form. The aim is to create a visual of a box on the screen when the user inputs height width and color.

form code:

```
const NewBoxForm = (props) => {

    const [height, setHeight] = useState();
    const [width, setWidth] = useState();
    const [color, setColor] = useState("");


    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const {value, name } = event.target;
        let change = name === "height" ? setHeight(value) : name === "width" ? setWidth(value) : 
       setColor(value);
    };
 
     const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        props.createBox(height, width, color);
     };

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
              <label htmlFor="height">Height</label>
              <input name="height" id="height"type="text" onChange={handleChange} value= 
              {height}>
              </input>
              <label htmlFor="width">Width</label>

              <input name="width" id="width" type="text"onChange={handleChange} value={width}>
              </input>
              <label htmlFor="color">Color</label>
              <input name="color" id="color"type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={color}>
              </input>
          </div>
            <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
};
```

I am passing the input from my form via a prop `props.createBox` to a function `create` which should update my `useState` state `boxes` but it doesn't. When I `console.log` `newBox` it only returns the `height`... can anyone see why?

```
const BoxList = () => {
const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState([{height: 0, width:0, color:""}]);

const boxesArray = boxes.map((box) => {
    return(
    <Box width={box.height}
         height={box.width}
         color={box.color}
    />
    )
});

const create = (newBox) => {
    console.log(newBox)
    setBoxes(boxes => [...boxes, newBox])
};


    return (
        <div>
            <NewBoxForm createBox={create} />
            {boxesArray}
        </div>

    );
};
```

Comment: you're only expecting one parameter in your function `create`. Should height, width, and color be sent as an object in `handleSubmit`? I.e. `props.createBox({height, width, color});` instead of `props.createBox(height, width, color);`

Comment: OK I will try that, I am expecting three parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
const create = (height, width, color) => {
    let newBox = {height: height, width: width, color: color};
    console.log(newBox);
    setBoxes(boxes => [...boxes, newBox])
};
```

Comment: With ES6 you don't have to repeat object name:values to contruct an object when there are variables with the exact same names, you can just pass these directly like `{ height, width, color }`.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending three separate variables in your handleSubmit call instead of one object.

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.createBox(height, width, color);
 };
```

should be:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.createBox({height, width, color});
 };
```

console.log is only logging the height because that is the first parameter you're sending.